# How to define a Compose Key in terminal (no desktop environment)?

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard-layout, keymap, compose-key

I would like to define a `compose` key on my system (it's a Debian Sid "Wheezy"). I have no Xorg (and don't want any desktop environment). Only in terminal. I would like to set it up on my `Alt-Gr` key (right `Alt`). I've tried for a while but I can't figure out how to set it up.

I've been investigating and found some directions. But I don't know what to do with that.

`$ showkey` gives me the keycode of my `Alt-Gr` key (#100)

`$ dumpkeys` and `$ dumpkeys --compose-only` output "the current contents of the keyboard's driver", in the format specified by `keymaps`, according to the `man` page

`$ loadkeys` load a keyboard translation table

I'm sure it's not that difficult but I can't figure out how to deal with that ...

Comment: I posted my questions on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44453, maybe I'll have some more answers ... I'm not sure whether it should be deleted from here or not?

Answer (score 2):

In a plain console -- no graphical environment -- the default 'Compose' key is usually assigned to the 'prt sc' key.

Your distro may vary.

See the man pages for 'keytables' 'dumpkeys' and 'loadkeys' for more.